# How to "absolutely" center an equation

Tags: alignment

[image]

How could I set the \to and \mapsto to be in the center (in the middle) of the page.

What I have is this:

```
\begin{align}
f|_{A} \colon A & \to Y \\
x \in A & \mapsto f|_{A}(x):=f(x)\in Y
\end{align}
```

and it is aligning \to and \mapsto but moving the whole equation to the left. How could I obtain everything in the middle?

I have "solved it" with this:

```
\begin{align}
 \quad \quad \quad \quad f|_{A} \colon A     & \to Y \\
x \in A & \mapsto f|_{A}(x):=f(x)\in Y
\end{align}
```

But it doesn't seem like the correct way.

Disclaimer 1: I'm new to LaTeX

Disclaimer 2: It's not fully LaTeX, is mathjax running on obsidian.

Comment: Welcome! Mathjax is not really TeX, so likely offtopic here.

Comment: mathjax specific questions are off topic as that is javascript not tex, normally you can phrase things so it covers both but here I suspect you want a css nswer on positioning teh math block which would be off topic

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can switch to LaTeX, I suggest you use a combination of `\hphantom` and `\mathllap` commands to the left of the `\to` symbol in row 1 (`\mathllap` is a macro that's provided by the `mathtools` package, as superset of the `amsmath` package.) The argument of `\hphantom` in row 1 should be what's to the right of the `\mapsto` symbol in row 2.

I would also replace `:=` with `\coloneqq`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \mathllap and \coloneqq macros
\usepackage{showframe} % draw framelines around text block

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\hphantom{f|_{A}(x)\coloneqq f(x)\in Y} % invisible
\mathllap{f|^{}_{A} \colon A} 
   &\to Y \\
x \in A 
   &\mapsto f|^{}_{A}(x)\coloneqq f(x)\in Y
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked in Mathjax/Obsidian too :)